# ggimage: Custom image from computer rather than from web

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggimage

The following graph can be produced from the R code given below. The images used in the graph are fetched from website. I'm wondering how to use images from computer.

[image]

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")

set.seed(2017-02-21)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                y = rnorm(10),
                image = sample(c("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png",
                                 "https://jeroenooms.github.io/images/frink.png"),
                               size=10, replace = TRUE)
                )

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image), size=.05)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very simple, you have just to set the directory where you have saved the .png files you want to use:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")
set.seed(2017-02-21)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                y = rnorm(10),
                image = sample(c("C:/YourDirectory/juventus.png",
                                 "C:/YourDirectory/sampdoria.png"),
                               size=10, replace = TRUE)
)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image), size=.05)
```

and you get the following result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Scipione for useful answer. I'd appreciate if you guide me how to put one image as a single plot. I mean neither points nor labels but only one full plot size image. Thanks